# How can I determine a relation, given the raw data for three variables?

Tags: multiple-regression

I have a dataset relating two variables to a result, as shown in the image below.

[image: image showing 2 variables related to a result]

In the image Variable 1 is held constant, and plotted against different values of Variable 2, and the result is shown. I have several entries for Variable 1 (though I can have as many intervals as I like. What I'm trying to do is determine an equation that gives Result as a function of Variable 1 and 2. i.e.

```
Result (Var1, Var2) where 0 >= Variable 1, Variable 2 <= 100
```

It seems like it should be a simple thing to do, but I'm not quite sure how to start.

Comment: Are these plots of actual *data*? If so, you must have an enormous dataset which exhibits no appreciable scatter, making this purely a problem of mathematical discovery (and you might want to point [Eureqa](http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa) at it.) Otherwise, please describe your *raw* data.

Comment: It sounds like you have a multiple regression situation. Note that "multivariate" usually refers to having >1 *response* variable, not >1 input variable. Also note that you seem to have **3** variables (2 covariates & 1 output variable), not 2.  The data / fitted lines you display here are all cases where var1 is >0, is what you are trying to figure out what is likely to happen if var1 were <=0?

Comment: whuber. Thanks for the tip on Eureqa, I've just had a little play and it seems like a very useful tool! I couldn't find a way to give it multiple datasets though - i.e. it seems to only fit to 1 of the lines in the above graph. A slightly bigger version of the data set (not that big) is available here: http://goo.gl/NMptB

Comment: gung. Thank you for the clarification - I should have checked I was using the correct terminology. I've edited the question accordingly. var 1 and var 2 always take values between (and including) 0 and 100. I am attempting to find a relation that allows me to calculate Result for any value of Var1,Var2 because the data you see is smoothed experimental data.

Comment: We cannot do a whole lot with *smoothed* data: the smoothing has thrown away *all* the information needed to evaluate the goodness of fit and has also added smoothing artifacts. Please start over by sharing the particulars of the actual experimental data.